# timeline chart + bubble with rCharts

Tags: r, rcharts

I'm trying to do a time series analysis of crime happening like theft. I'm able to create a timeline chart using rChart with Highchart. I need to highlight holidays, is it possble to have bubble chart inside timeline chart
Thanks

Comment: you should provide a reproducible example of what you have so far tried.